# Calculate percentage of cell values using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA, I am trying to calculate percentage of one cell value, but it is not working. I am giving percentage value from Textfield which I have designed for fetching values from excel using macros.

Here I have written some piece of code,

```
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Requirements_Ranking")
RowCount = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
RowCount = "S" & RowCount

var1 = "50"
If TextBox1.Value = var1 Then

    Sheets("Requirements_Ranking").Range("B3:B10").Copy
    Sheets("Coverage").Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    var2=(RowCount*var1)/100
```

Comment: What is RowCount? Is it a number (as the second line of code suggests) or is it a string (as the third line of code suggests where you add an "S" to the number of used rows)?
What is TextBox1? Is it a form control or an ActiveX control from the developer tab or a simple shape?

Comment: What is your "RowCount" supposed to be? It looks like you need it to be an integer (to divide with), but have it as a string (adding "S"?).  If you want to count the number of used rows in column S, use this `RowCount = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: RowCount will tells how many cells in a column(ex:S1-S5096). And TextBox1 is an ActiveX contol from developer tab, in that control i am giving value, based on that value result should come...!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

var1 = 50 If cint(TextBox1.Value) = var1 Then

Comment: Hi Sandesh, your piece of code is working, my intention is calculating the formula of percentage, for that I used var2=(RowCount*var1)/100, in this line I am getting error that 'Type mismatch'.

Comment: use var2=(RowCount*cint(var1))/100.   Additionally you have to get a better understanding of datatypes.  :)